# How to make eclipse output to console window AND a file?

Tags: eclipse

I think the question title says it all

I want eclipse to write to the console debug window and also to a file. 
How can I do that? (working on a mac)

Comment: In the run configuration, in the tab _Common_ enable and set _Output File_.

Comment: Thanks, worked, silly me

Answer (score 0):

In the **run configuration** (*Run > Run Configurations...*), in the tab ***Common*** enable and set ***Output File***.